# JasperReport not displaying image when converted to pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am working on a spring-mvc project and I am using JasperReports for reporting purposes. I have a link that generates a report in pdf format. Link is working fine and report is generated, but **the problem is pdf report is not displaying the image**. Snippet from my jrxml file:

```
<frame>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="67" uuid="0af2e978-7c0c-4805-afb4-4069d1297a12"/>
    <image onErrorType="Blank" evaluationTime="Report">
        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="67" uuid="c572c836-8d67-480a-b1b1-d603940e6c74"/>
        <imageExpression><![CDATA["images/geLogo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
    </image>
</frame>
```

I checked again and the image is present in my webapp/images folder in my project. I have used this same image in my jsp page, it is working.

Code used to generate the pdf from JasperReport:

```
try {
        JasperPrint print = service.loadReceipt(RECEIPT_NAME, paymentId);
        pdfFile = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
        OutputStream outStream = res.getOutputStream();
        res.setContentType("application/pdf");
        res.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=Receipt.pdf");
        outStream.write(pdfFile);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }
```

**Can you tell me why image is not coming in the pdf, though the displays the image in JasperReport Designer with the same path.** I have used JasperReports plugin in my eclipse to design reports. I deploy the project in jboss 6.4 through war file.
Thank you in advance.
**-------UPDATE--------**
I got the idea of checking the structure of project inside war from @KDavid-Valerio answer. It is different from the actual project structure. war structure looks something like this:

```
Project
    images
        image1.jpg
        image2.jpg
    WEB-INF
        classes
            reports
                report1.jrxml
                report2.jrxml
```

It still doesn't seem to work.

**-------UPDATE--------**
Code that fills the jasper report:

```
public JasperPrint loadReceipt(String reportName, String paymentId, String imagePath) {
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JasperReport report = null;
        JasperPrint print = null;

        try {
            if (jrReportMap == null) {
                jrReportMap = new HashMap<String, JasperReport>();
            }           

            if (jrReportMap.get(reportName) == null) {
                report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportManager.load(reportName));
                jrReportMap.put(reportName, report);
                log.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS, "--- Report Compilation done --- " + reportName);
            } else {
                report = jrReportMap.get(reportName);
                log.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS, "--- Report already Compiled --- " + reportName);
            }

            params.put("paymentId", paymentId);
            params.put("realPath", imagePath);

            try {
                Connection conn = reportDataSource.getConnection();
                print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, conn);
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("--- SQL ERR - to get connection -----");
                log.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, "--- Report already Compiled --- " + reportName);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JRException e1) {
            log.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, "Oops... Something wrong while rendering the report !!!");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return print;
    }
```

Comment: The path used by JasperReport at runtime it's different from the one used by the designer. In your java code you have to put the path of the image relative to the .jasper file inside your WAR.

Comment: I tried many different paths. Nothing seems to work. I have even tried an external path like C:/something. It doesn't work.

Comment: I'm going to writing an answer that explains how I did it in my project. I hope that this can help you.

Comment: That will be great @KDavid-Valerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found  a solution to this problem using ServletContext.

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```

Autowire this dependency then use its method `getRealPath()` to get the real path of any directory after your project is deployed. I found that it keeps changing everytime I deploy the code in jboss.

Code that generates pdf:

```
 byte[] pdfFile = null;
    String realPath = context.getRealPath("/images/");
    try {
        JasperPrint print = service.loadReceipt(RECEIPT_NAME, paymentId, realPath);
        pdfFile = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
        OutputStream outStream = res.getOutputStream();
        res.setContentType("application/pdf");
        res.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=Receipt.pdf");
        outStream.write(pdfFile);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
}
```

Code to fill the report:

```
public JasperPrint loadReceipt(String reportName, String paymentId, String realPath) {
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JasperReport report = null;
        JasperPrint print = null;

        try {
            if (jrReportMap == null) {
                jrReportMap = new HashMap<String, JasperReport>();
            }           

            if (jrReportMap.get(reportName) == null) {
                report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportManager.load(reportName));
                jrReportMap.put(reportName, report);
                log.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS, "--- Report Compilation done --- " + reportName);
            } else {
                report = jrReportMap.get(reportName);
                log.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS, "--- Report already Compiled --- " + reportName);
            }

            params.put("paymentId", paymentId);
            params.put("realPath", realPath);

            try {
                Connection conn = reportDataSource.getConnection();
                print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, conn);
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("--- SQL ERR - to get connection -----");
                log.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, "--- Report already Compiled --- " + reportName);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JRException e1) {
            log.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, "Oops... Something wrong while rendering the report !!!");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return print;
    }
```

And finally the jrxml snippet:

```
<frame>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="67" uuid="0af2e978-7c0c-4805-afb4-4069d1297a12"/>
    <image onErrorType="Blank" evaluationTime="Report">
        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="67" uuid="c572c836-8d67-480a-b1b1-d603940e6c74"/>
        <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{realPath}+"/geLogo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
    </image>
</frame>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<imageExpression><![CDATA["images/geLogo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>`

use a parameter.
E.g.,:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{imagePath}]]></imageExpression>
```

imagePath it's a String that contains the relative URL of the image inside the WAR.

For example, if your WAR has the following structure:

---

```
 YourWebProject
      WebContent
           reports
                report1.jasper
                report2.jasper
                ...
                reportn.jasper
            images
                geLogo.jpg
```

When you fill the imagePath parameter you have to give it the path of the image relative to the report path. If you want to user geLogo.jpg image, it will be:

```
String imagePath = "../images/geLogo.jpg";
```

Comment: I never thought of checking the structure of project inside the war. Now i checked it, it is different from what I see in the eclipse workspace.<br/>Following is the structure inside the war.<br/>`Project
 images
  image1.jpg
  image2.jpg
 WEB-INF
  classes
   reports
    report1.jrxml
    report2.jrxml`

Comment: @Waquar if you have founded useful my answer, please check it as useful :)

Comment: @Waquar can you post the java code that fills the report?

Comment: I updated the question. Structure not showing properly in comments. But it doesn't seem to work for me. Image is still not coming in the pdf.

Comment: @Waquar please add also the code that generates the report. Maybe inside the loadReceipt method?

Comment: I'll update the question with the code that fills the report @KDavid - Valerio

Comment: I updated the question with the code that fills the report and also implemented the solution you suggested. It doesn't seem to work. @KDavid - Valerio

Comment: @Waquar I've checked the jasper report source code, it should work. Maybe the imagePath it's wrong. Can you post the imagePath value?